# Can Solve[...] be used for set math? If so, how? If not, how else?

Tags: sets

I'm a recreational user who loves using the product.

I'm looking for a strategy to solve the following question using Mathematica.

The question is from a sample actuarial exam. I can solve this with pencil and paper, but I'm fascinated (and stumped) about how to solve this in Mathematica.  Any hints? Thanks!

THE QUESTION: An auto insurance company has 10,000 policyholders.

Each policyholder is classified as
(i) young or old;
(ii) male or female; and
(iii) married or single.

Of these policyholders,

- 3000 are young,
- 4600 are male, and
- 7000 are married.

The policyholders can also be classified as

- 1320 young males,
- 3010 married males, and
- 1400 young married persons.

Finally, 600 of the policyholders are young married males.

Calculate the number of the company’s policyholders who are young, female, and single.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The tedious part of this is writing all the equations

```
ages = {young, old};
sexes = {female, male};
wed = {single, married};

equations = {Sum[n[young, j, k], {j, sexes}, {k, wed}] == 
    3000,
   Sum[n[i, male, k], {i, ages}, {k, wed}] == 4600,
   Sum[n[i, j, married], {i, ages}, {j, sexes}] == 7000,
   Sum[n[young, male, k], {k, wed}] == 1320,
   Sum[n[i, male, married], {i, ages}] == 3010,
   Sum[n[young, j, married], {j, sexes}] == 1400,
   n[young, male, married] == 600};

Solve[equations]
(* {{n[old, female, married] -> 3190, 
  n[old, male, married] -> 2410, n[old, male, single] -> 870, 
  n[young, female, married] -> 800, n[young, female, single] -> 880, 
  n[young, male, married] -> 600, n[young, male, single] -> 720}} *)
```

There might be a slightly more concise way of expressing this.

Comment: Thank you @mikado! That's an interesting approach. A remarkable thing is this solution makes no use of the population size (10,000), which I imagined would be required.  May I ask, in the interest of my learning, where do the `n[...]` terms come from? I've not seen that in the language. I use `N[...]` and `...// N` all the time, but `n[...]`?

Comment: `n` is simply a variable name.  I could have used any Mathematica identifier `x`, `number`,.... Assuming I've not made a mistake, I have 7 equations in 7 unknowns.  The number of old, single females is not mentioned, but could be calculated by including the grand total (which I omitted inadvertently).